# How do I calculate the likelihood of a particular combination?

Tags: probability, combinations

I work for a university, and we run an outreach program, for secondary school students. I'm trying to work out the ethnic profile of the students who have attended our outreach events.

The information I have:

- What events happened in which school.
- How many students attended each event.
- How many students of each ethnicity are registered at each school.

I don't know, and need to estimate, how many students from each ethnic group attended an activity.

For example, if I know that a school held an event with 10 attendees, and the school is 100% Martians and 0% Venusians, there is a probability of 1 that the all 10 event attendees were Martians. Therefore, I know that the % of Martians in the school is the same as the % of Martians who were event attendees in that school.

What if the school is 50% Martians and 50% Venusians? How do I work out the probability that the ethnic profile of the event matched the ethnic profile of the school?

Comment: You could simplify multiply the probability that a student is in a particular ethnic group by the number of students attending the event to get the expected number of students from each ethnic group (assuming the event is not culturally specific).  That said, you would need to know the actual ethnicities of  the students who attend the event to compare that with those probabilities.

Comment: I know that if there is a group of 5 students, and the school is 60% Martian and 40% Venusians, the most likely composition is 3 M, 2 V. But what I want to know is *how* likely this combination is.